# Database spit out only specific ID's rows data from list of links instead of ALL rows in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page that spits out the ID # and the Last Name from a table in a database.

I want to be able to click on the ID #, have it go to a new page, and view the rows info for that specfic ID # only.

Here is some code from my print.php page where it lists out the ID # and the Last Name which works great.

ID # = m_id

Last Name = m2_2

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'name');

if($db->connect_errno > 0)
{ 
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); 
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test_gina` ORDER BY m_id DESC";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

if($row['m_id'] =="x"){echo " ";}else{ echo '<a href="id.php">'; echo $row['m_id'];}echo '</a>';

if($row['m2_2'] =="x"){echo " ";}else{echo $row['m2_2'];}echo '<br>';
```

When it goes to the id.php, it shows ALL the rows from the table in the database.

I am not that expierenced in databases, so I know I am doing it wrong, but how do I "connect" the 2 pages to have id.php only show the information for that specfic ID #?

Here is some of my code from my id.php page.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'name');

if($db->connect_errno > 0)
{ 
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); 
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test_gina` ORDER BY m_id DESC";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

if($row['m_id'] =="x"){echo " ";}else{echo '<strong>ID #:</strong>'; echo $row['m_id'];}echo '</br>';
echo "";if($row['m_P'] =="x"){echo " ";}else
{
switch($row['m_P'])
{
case "35310":
echo "<strong>Persons living/Household:</strong> 1"; 
break;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly!!!

Comment: Where is the HTML navigation code that takes you from the current page to your "id.php" page?

Comment: That is done on print.php using PHP code because it has to call out to the database to get the ID # and the Last Name.

Comment: if($row['m_id'] =="x"){echo " ";}else{ echo '<a href="id.php">'; echo $row['m_id'];}echo '</a>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look into writing "clean" codes. That being said, in your "print.php" replace

```
echo '<a href="id.php">'; echo $row['m_id'];}echo '</a>'
```

with

```
echo '<a href="id.php?id='. $row['m_id']. '">'. $row['m_id']. '</a>'
```

Notice I'm using concatenation, rather than multiple `echo` statements.

Briefly put, the "?" and what follows it in the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag is what is called a query string.

Then, in your "id.php" file, you get hold of the query string using the `GET` super global, like below:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

your query string should then look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test_gina` WHERE m_id = $id ORDER BY m_id DESC";
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. You may want to mark it as the accepted answer to help someone coming after you.